# How does plyr merge two columns of different data.frames with same names but different values

Tags: r, plyr

While merging 3 data.frames using `plyr` library, I encounter some values with the same name but with different values each in different data.frames.

How does the `do.call(rbind.fill,list)` treat this problem: by arithmetic or geometric average?

Comment: Can you supply an example of your data or at least the output of `str()`?

Answer (score 3):

From the help page for rbind.fill:

```
Combine data.frames by row, filling in missing columns. rbinds a list of data frames 
filling missing columns with NA.
```

So I'd expect it to fill columns that do not match with NA. It is also not necessary to use `do.call()` here.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 4:5)
dat2 <- data.frame(b = 3:2, c = 8:9)
dat3 <- data.frame(a = 5:6, c = 1:2)

rbind.fill(dat1, dat2, dat3)
   a  b  c
1  1  4 NA
2  2  5 NA
3 NA  3  8
4 NA  2  9
5  5 NA  1
6  6 NA  2
```

Are you expecting something different?

Comment: hi again. i am working with proteins. so in column 32 of data.frame1 sat i have a protein named QPUYT and

Comment: how do i merge the same names but different values with geometric average ? that is, i wish the output to have one representative of the same name that has the geometric average as a value, and not just having 2 entries as the ware. in more word, i wish to average the values and leave the names.  thanks

Comment: @Yigael - Please update your question following the guidelines outlined in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. You'll get far superior answers compared to me taking a WAG as to what you really want. If I understand your last comment, does `colMeans(dat, na.rm = TRUE)` where `dat` is the `rbind`ed data.frames do what you want? I should also mention that the http://www.bioconductor.org/ project may have tools specifically designed to assist in this type of analysis.

Comment: @yigael merging is what ‘ddply‘ does well.  ‘ddply(my data frame,.(namecolumns),summarize,value=geomean(value))‘